# error when auto-loading second form from mainform at startup in delphi

Tags: forms, delphi, access-violation, delphi-xe7

First time amateur programmer here. Hoping for some help.  Working with Delphi XE7.

I have a Mainform, which has a button that brings up a second form.  On the initial startup, I want to click the button that brings up the second form, so that both forms will both be visible.  I then save this into a config file so that it doesn't do it on each load.

When tracing inside, I see `Form2` is nil, and I get an Access Violation error. I believe the issue is that the MainForm hasn't completely loaded yet to bring up `Form2`. Or that `Form2` has not been created yet, and thus can't be brought up.

I have tried to add delays to wait for the MainForm to load.  I have tried a timer. I have tried searching for other answers, but still haven't found one that helps. I hope someone here can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `Form2` has not been created yet when the `MainForm` is still in the process of being created.  You have to wait until `Form2` has been created before you can then show it.

The easiest way to do that is to simply set the `Form2.Visible` property to True at design-time (secondary Forms are set to `Visible=False` by default), and then make sure `Form2` is set to auto-create in the project options (secondary Forms are not auto-created by default). Let `Form2` show itself automatically after it is created at startup.

However, if your button needs to do things to setup `Form2`, then you have to delay the button click until after `Form2` is created.  I like to use a delayed window message for that purpose, eg:

```
const
  WM_DELAYED_STARTUP = WM_APP + 1;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure WMDelayedStartup(var Message: TMessage); message WM_DELAYED_STARTUP;
  end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, WM_DELAYED_STARTUP, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TMainForm.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //...
  Form2.Show;
  //...
end;

procedure TMainForm.WMDelayedStartup(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Button1.Click;
end;
```

A timer will also work fine:

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    StartupTimer: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure StartupTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartupTimer.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TMainForm.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //...
  Form2.Show;
  //...
end;

procedure TMainForm.StartupTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartupTimer.Enabled := False;
  Button1.Click;
end;
```

Or, you could use the MainForm's `OnShow` event (if you show the MainForm only once and don't hide it during the app's lifetime):

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Click;
end;

procedure TMainForm.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //...
  Form2.Show;
  //...
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend that after have your project opened, execute Shift + Ctrl + F11 shortcut and select forms option as follows
[[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFTeu.png). After this, select your Form2 in Auto-Create forms, move his to Available Forms and click on the button Ok.
After this, change the lines of code that call the Form2 to:

`Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
 Form2.ShowModal;
 FreeAndNil(Form2)`

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Cheers,